# From a .NET library, how to check if the RUNNING assembly/app is in Debug build (without Debugger attached)?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, .net-core

I am making a class library `Foo` (Xamarin Android Library if relevant but I prefer a general .NET solution if possible), and I need something like this:

```
if (builtInDebugConfig) 
{
    this.DoSomething();
}
```

Now `Foo.dll` will certainly be compiled in Release mode when the above code is called. Therefore `#if` is not possible for sure, <strike>`Conditional` should not work also (correct me if I am wrong, I've read it's a compiler attribute too)</strike> (the answer of the question and my test confirms `Conditional` works). The closest I could think of is `Debugger.IsAttached`, however most of the time we test apps without a debugger attached.

**Is there a way to detect if the *calling* assembly is compiled with `DEBUG` symbol/config?** If possible I don't want the calling (app) code to have something like this in every app because it defeats the purpose:

```
#if DEBUG
    Foo.IsDebug = true;
#endif
```

UPDATE: Clarification for why I want that: I want to enable Debug codes (i.e enable WebView debug signal) if the calling app is in in development and don't want such code to exist in final view. That's why I am interested in a solution that prevent such code leaking to Release build.

Comment: There is no such thing as *the* "debug config"... It's just combination of defined symbols and compilation options that happen to be shown with "DEBUG" as the config name... You need to decide what exactly you are interested in and check that...

Comment: create a DEBUG compiler symbol and use #ifdef to check for it in your code

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thanks, I added the clarification to my question as why I want to do that. If possible, I want my library to take care of checking the build to make sure the end-developers do not accidentally forget the remove Debug call in the Release build.

Comment: @Jason I mentioned that in my question. Unfortunately `#if` directive is compile-time and so must be added to each app project and not a single point from my library.

Comment: I don't think you can tell, in general, which conditional compilation symbols were defined during compilation for an already-compiled assembly. Maybe you should look for [`DebuggableAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggableattribute?view=netcore-3.1) on the calling assembly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3880395/4984832

Comment: @JoeSewell thanks, it works, just tested. Both checking for `DebuggableAttribute` and using `Conditional` works.

Comment: @LukeVo just to reiterate - there is absolutely nothing to stop someone to add "DEBUG" symbol to the release config. If you have real concerns that something should not show up in production code you'd better to check for that instead.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes I understand. It's not so critical but I don't think anyone would want to add a `DEBUG` symbol to Release build. But sure, that's a nice check to do before releasing anyway. Thanks.

Comment: @LukeVo just wait till someone needs to debug something in deployed app :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Conditional` in `Foo` to decorate a method - any calls to that method will depend on whether the *calling* code defines the relevant symbol. So something like:

```cs
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public void MaybeSetDebugMode()
{
    // Remember the decision
}
```

Then the calling code can unconditionally write code calling `MaybeSetDebugMode`, and the call will only *actually* be compiled in if `DEBUG` is defined when the calling code is compiled. The method in `Foo` itself will be compiled into `Foo.dll` regardless of the symbols defined when you compile it.

That's not the same as `#if`, which *does* depend on the symbols when you're compiling your code.

Note that this is how [`Debug.WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline?view=netcore-3.1) etc work.

One downside of this: this code *absolutely* will exist in the "final build" unless you take more action. It has to, given that the existence of code in Foo.dll can't change depending on what calls it.

So you *may* actually want to use `#if` instead, for example:

```cs
#if FINAL_BUILD
public void MaybeSetDebugMode()
{
    // This method exists so that the calling code will still build
    // with the final DLL, but there won't be any "interesting" code
    // for anyone to find.
}

#else

public void MaybeSetDebugMode()
{
    // Interesting code goes here. This code won't be included in the final build,
    // but callers can call it unconditionally, because there'll be an empty
    // method in the final build.
}
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks, just tested, can confirm this work, `Conditional` is indeed not at compile time, at least not at the library compilation.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the downside, it's okay. It's not like we leak important code in the Release build, they are just enabling some Debug switches.

Comment: I discover something interesting. It seems `Conditional` considers the symbol in the _calling_ assembly. For example, in my library, I did call `DoSomething()` but it isn't executed. However, it's executed if I call the method from the app project.

Comment: @LukeVo: That's exactly what I wrote: "any calls to that method will depend on whether the calling code defines the relevant symbol". That's as much the case when the calling code is within the same assembly as it is when the calling code is in a different assembly.

Comment: Thanks. While it already works well for me, I wonder if it's possible to make my case works further as my original intention: _from my own library_, I call the method. The method executes if the entry assembly has `DEBUG` symbol, not the assembly of the calling (library) code.

Comment: @LukeVo: Not with `Conditional`, no. The impact is at compile-time, which means that when the call is from within your library, you can't change the compiled IL in your library just by compiling a *different* assembly differently. You could have multiple methods in your library which are *themselves* controlled with Conditional, but that's going to get ugly quickly.

Comment: Thanks, totally understand. I was just wondering if there is any way to do that. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimpour: Please don't use comments on unrelated posts to try to get attention for questions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments and answers, I've found two working solutions, both are great but I think I will use `Conditional` in my final project. `IsExecutingDebug` checks if `DebuggableAttribute` is present in the Entry assembly, while `Conditional` is explained in [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61467293/653457).

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {

        public bool IsExecutingDebug()
        {
#if DEBUG
            Console.WriteLine("Debug in lib");
#endif

            return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().IsInDebug();
        }

        [Conditional("DEBUG")]
        public void ExecuteInDebugOnly()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi!");
        }

    }
}

namespace System
{

    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static bool IsInDebug(this Assembly assembly)
        {
            return assembly.GetCustomAttributes<DebuggableAttribute>().Any();
        }
    }

}
```