# C# library method with [Conditional("RELEASE")] still called in Debug build

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, compilation, conditional-compilation

I have the following code in `MyLib.dll`:

```cs
    [Obsolete("This method is for debugging only. Remove all calls to this method once done.")]
    public void SetLaunchCount(int count)
    {
        ThrowOnReleaseBuild();
        launchEntry.Set(count);
    }

    [Conditional("RELEASE")]
    static void ThrowOnReleaseBuild()
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("This method must not be called outside of DEBUG build"); ;
    }
```

When I tested it using a project (MAUI in my case) in the same solution, it works fine. However, when packing it and uploading it to Nuget (through our private Github Nuget feed), calling `SetLaunchCount` always throw and the stack trace shows call to `ThrowOnReleaseBuild`.

I have double checked and the Debug build indeed has `DEBUG` symbol (and more precisely, no `RELEASE` symbol):

[image]

I also tried adding another `Debug.WriteLine` method to confirm it:

[image]

Why is it not working? I checked the (decompiled) source code of `Debug.WriteLine` for example, and it's coded just like my method:

```cs
        [Conditional("DEBUG")]
        public static void WriteLine(string? message) =>
            s_provider.WriteLine(message);
```

EDIT: adding some more information:

- The library was built in Release profile.
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61467293/653457) on my previous question about using `Conditional`. Somehow it does not work now.

Comment: If it throws then it means the package was compiled using the 'RELEASE' flag set and the code is there. Binaries in your NuGet package were already compiled and have this method there. If now you use it inside other code compiled in DEBUG, your dll will not magically recompile itself and not throw.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik that does not make sense though because `Debug.WriteLine` uses the same technique. Though you are right I forgot to mention the library was compiled with `RELEASE` flag.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61467293/653457) as well for reference

Comment: I think you get that answer wrong. It would work like that if you would call that method directly not via other method. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as expected. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute?view=net-7.0) you can read (emphasis mine) that

> Applying ConditionalAttribute to a method indicates to compilers that **a call to the method should not be compiled** into Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL) unless the conditional compilation symbol that is associated with ConditionalAttribute is defined.

So when you use `Debug.WriteLine` and you compile your code with RELEASE or DEBUG flag, it's not that the code inside the `Debug.WriteLine` is removed. It's the call itself that's not there - that's why "it works".

So in your case:
In DEBUG mode the `SetLaunchCount` method is affected in the following way:

```
[Obsolete("This method is for debugging only. Remove all calls to this method once done.")]
public void SetLaunchCount(int count)
{
    ThrowOnReleaseBuild(); <-- this is removed in DEBUG, and not in RELEASE
    launchEntry.Set(count);
}
```

When you pack this into NuGet in Release mode, the method is there and if you compile your code in DEBUG or RELEASE doesn't affect it as it's not your code that calls the method that is marked as `Conditional` attribute. You only call `SetLaunchCount`.

If you would make the method `ThrowOnReleaseBuild` public and call it from your code, even if it would be in the Nuget - it would work as you expect as the call to that method would be there or not depending on the condition.

Comment: Yeah I was contemplating about that too and that seems to be the case. I will run through MSIL code later to confirm but I think you are right.